# It's possible to use WHERE_IN query with a composite key with Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE (sales_code, payment_code, client_id) IN ( ('1118', '1', '99'), ('1119', '1', '99') );

can i do the same thing with laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for this would be to use **raw expressions**, as follows:

```
$query = DB::table('sales')
            ->whereRaw("(sales_code, payment_code, client_id) IN ( ('1118',1, 99), ('1119',1,99))")
            ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Thanks, i think is the best solution! i didn't find anything besides that.